# Update or change value of a key in .cong file in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have `.conf` file with Key Value pair like -

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
key3=value3
```

In my `python` code I have dictionary like

```
conf = {'key1' : 'newvalue1', 'key3' : 'newvalue3'}
```

I want to update value of given keys from dictionary in file by using `python`. How can I achieve it. I tried below but it is not working

```
def save_settings(conf):
for line in fileinput.input(files=["%s" % (CONF)], inplace=1):
    line = re.sub('key1=.*', 'key1=%s' % (conf['key1']), line.rstrip())
    line = re.sub('key3=.*', 'key1=%s' % (conf['key1']), line.rstrip())
    print(line)
return "true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution would be to use a standard python library like [Configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html). Alternatively you can do a simple approach.

First we read the *old* conf file:

```
with open("conf.conf") as f:
    conf_lines = [line.strip().split("=") for line  in f.readlines()]
```

Here our `conf_lines` look like:

```
[['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2'], ['key3', 'value3']]
```

since this is a nested list, we convert this into `dict` object

```
conf_lines = {line[0]: line[1] for line in conf_lines}
```

Now we have `conf_lines` as dict:

```
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
```

Our new values are also in dict as `conf = {'key1' : 'newvalue1', 'key3' : 'newvalue3'}` so we can just update `conf_lines` using

```
conf_lines.update(conf)
```

now our `conf_lines` look like

```
{'key1': 'newvalue1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'newvalue3'}
```

And we write this change into conf file:

```
with open("new_conf.conf", "w") as f:
    for key, value in conf_lines.items():
        f.write(f"{key}={value}" + os.linesep)
```